# Existing E-mail check (Django + Javascript/Ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, django

I've been trying to build an E-mail validator with Django and Javascript/Ajax, but I'm stuck. I get the Ajax response

```
{response: "This field is required.", email: false}
email: false
response: "This field is required."
```

But it's always the same, even if I fill in the E-mail field.

This is my **view.py**

```
@requires_csrf_token
def email_check(request):
    email = request.POST.get('email', False)
    if request.is_ajax():
        if email:
            query_email = CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email)
            if query_email.exists():
                res = "{0} is already in use.".format(email)
            else:
                res = "This E-mail is ok."
            ajax_vars = {'response': res, 'email': email}
            json_data = json.dumps(ajax_vars)
        else:
            res = "This field is required."
            ajax_vars = {'response': res, 'email': email}
            json_data = json.dumps(ajax_vars)

        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
```

This is the **template** and the **script**

```
<form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email">E-mail</a>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
            // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
        }
    }
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#email").focusout(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        var email = $('#email').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/email_check/",
            type: "POST",            
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data : { 
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken, 
                email: email
            },
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm probably skipping some steps, can you help me understand which they are?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure its the cause of the issue but your `input` has an erroneous `</a>` tag and no label tag

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, but that doesn't seem to be the problem, unfortunately!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the following args from `$.ajax()`

```
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json",
```

And it'll work.

I tested it locally, when content type is `application/json` it doesn't seem to work as expected. Maybe django expects the content type to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for a POST request.